# How to set nested list to parent item after distinct

Tags: rx-java2

I have begun to deal with RxJava and its operators. It became interesting to me how to set nested list to parent item after distinct.

<s>Lazy</s> Simple example:

```
    Observable.just(parentItem)
            .flatMapIterable { parentItem -> parentItem.array }
            .distinct { arrayItem -> arrayItem.name }
            .toList()

            /// other stuff which have to return the observable, not item list
```

Please, tell me as to make it truly and correctly

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you want to do?

Comment: I have a simple POJO class which contains the array list. I want to remove duplicates in array and set result back in a class by RxJava